# selenium - python - NameError: name 'url_search' is not defined

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to reproduce the work of @lukebarousse with his Job_Analysis repo on GitHub: https://github.com/lukebarousse/Job_Analysis

Code from the LinkedIn.ipynb jupyter notebook:

Cell_1:

```
import time
import datetime
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import os
import csv
import logging
from dotenv import load_dotenv
```

Cell_2:

```
def create_logfile():
    date_time = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%d-%b-%y_%H:%M:%S')
    logfile = f"log/{date_time}.log"
    logging.basicConfig(filename=logfile, filemode='w', level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', datefmt='%d-%b-%y %H:%M:%S', force=True)
    logging.info(f'Log file {logfile} created')
    return logging

def create_file(file, logging):
    # delete existing file if re-running
    logging.info("Checking if current daily csv exists...")
    if os.path.exists(file):
        os.remove(file)
        logging.info(f"{file} deleted")
    else:
        logging.info(f"{file} ain't exist")
    
    # create file and add header
    logging.info("Creating daily csv file...")
    header = ['date_time', 'search_keyword', 'search_count', 'job_id', 'job_title', 'company', 'location', 'remote', 'update_time', 'applicants', 'job_pay', 'job_time', 'job_position', 'company_size', 'company_industry', 'job_details']
    with open(file, 'w') as f:
        w = csv.writer(f)
        w.writerow(header)
        logging.info(f"{file} created")

def login(logging):
    url_login = "https://www.linkedin.com/"

    # pulls login information from file called '.env' 
    # this file added to .gitignore so login details not shared
    load_dotenv()
    # .env file is of structure:
    # LINKEDIN_USERNAME=email@gmail.com
    # LINKEDIN_PASSWORD=password

    LINKEDIN_USERNAME = os.getenv('LINKEDIN_USERNAME')
    LINKEDIN_PASSWORD = os.getenv('LINKEDIN_PASSWORD')

    # setup chrome to run headless
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")

    # login to LinkedIn
    logging.info(f"Logging in to LinkedIn as {LINKEDIN_USERNAME}...")
    wd = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='./chromedriver', options=chrome_options)
    wd.get(url_login)
    wd.find_element(By.ID, "session_key").send_keys(LINKEDIN_USERNAME)
    wd.find_element(By.ID, "session_password").send_keys(LINKEDIN_PASSWORD)
    wd.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@class='sign-in-form__submit-button']").click()

    # random confirm acount information pop up that may come up
    try: 
        wd.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@class='primary-action-new']").click()
    except:
        pass
    logging.info("Log in complete. Scraping data...")

    return wd

def page_search(wd, search_location, search_keyword, search_remote, search_posted, search_page, search_count, file, logging):
    # wait time for events in seconds
    page_wait = 30
    click_wait = 5
    async_wait = 5

    # when retrying, number of attempts
    attempts = 3

    # navigate to search page
    url_search = f"https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search/?f_TPR={search_posted}&f_WRA={search_remote}&geoId=103644278&keywords={search_keyword}&location={search_location}&start={search_page}"
    wd.get(url_search)
    time.sleep(page_wait) # add sleep so don't get caught

    # find the number of results 
    search_count = wd.find_element(By.XPATH, "//small[@class='display-flex t-12 t-black--light t-normal']").text
    search_count = int(search_count.split(' ')[0].replace(',', ''))  # get number before space & remove comma (ex. "1,245 results")
    logging.info(f"Loading page {round(search_page/25) + 1} of {round(search_count/25)} for {search_keyword}'s {search_count} results...")

    # get all the job_id's for xpath for current page to click each element
    # running into errors with slow load (11-Aug)
    for attempt in range(attempts):
        try:
            search_results = wd.find_element(By.XPATH, "//ul[@class='jobs-search-results__list list-style-none']").find_elements_by_tag_name("li")
            result_ids = [result.get_attribute('id') for result in search_results if result.get_attribute('id') != '']
            break
        except:
            time.sleep(click_wait) # wait a few attempts, if not throw an exception and then skip to next page

    # cycle through each job_ids and steal the job data...muhahaha!
    list_jobs = [] #initate a blank list to append each page to
    for id in result_ids:
        try:
            job = wd.find_element(By.ID) 
            job_id = job.get_attribute("data-occludable-entity-urn").split(":")[-1]
            # select a job and start extracting information
            wd.find_element(By.XPATH, f"//div[@data-job-id={job_id}]").click()
        except:
            continue
            # exception likely to job deleteing need to go to next id

        for attempt in range(attempts):
            try:
                # from analysis 3 attempts at 5 second waits gets job titles 99.99% of time (11-Aug)
                job_title = wd.find_element(By.XPATH, "//h2[@class='t-24 t-bold']") # keep having issues with finding element
                job_title = job_title.text
                break
            except:
                job_title = ''
                time.sleep(click_wait)
        
        # Having issues finding xpath of company (Added 11-Aug)
        for attempt in range(attempts):
            try:
                job_top_card1 = wd.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[@class='jobs-unified-top-card__subtitle-primary-grouping mr2 t-black']").find_elements_by_tag_name("span")
                company = job_top_card1[0].text
                location = job_top_card1[1].text
                if len(job_top_card1) > 2: # only displays remote if selected, otherwise only 2 elements in list
                    remote = job_top_card1[2].text
                else:
                    remote = ''
                break
            except:
                company = ''
                location = ''
                remote = ''
                time.sleep(click_wait)
        
        for attempt in range(attempts):
            try:
                #multiple issues with job_top_card2 loading
                job_top_card2 = wd.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[@class='jobs-unified-top-card__subtitle-secondary-grouping t-black--light']").find_elements_by_tag_name("span")
                update_time = job_top_card2[0].text
                applicants = job_top_card2[1].text.split(' ')[0]
                break
            except: 
                update_time = '' # after #attempts leave as blank and move on
                applicants = '' # after #attempts leave as blank and move on
                time.sleep(click_wait)

        # Due to (slow) ASYNCHRONOUS updates, need wait times to get job_info
        job_time = '' # assigning as blanks as not important info and can skip if not obtained below
        job_position = ''
        job_pay = ''
        for attempt in range(attempts):
            try:
                # 1 - make sure HTML element is loaded
                element = WebDriverWait(wd, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='mt5 mb2']/div[1]")))
                # 2 - make sure text is loaded
                try:
                    job_info = element.text
                    if job_info != '':
                        # seperate job information on time requirements and position
                        job_info = job_info.split(" · ")
                        if len(job_info) == 1: # only one item means its job _time
                            job_pay = ''
                            job_time = job_info[0]
                            job_position = ''
                        elif (len(job_info) >= 2) and ("$" in job_info[0]): # if has money symbol then seperate
                            job_pay = job_info[0]
                            job_time = job_info[1]
                            if(len(job_info)>= 3): # check if job_info is required
                                job_position = job_info[2]
                            else:
                                job_position = ''
                        else: # else condition satisifies the last condition
                            job_time = job_info[0]
                            job_position = job_info[1]
                            job_pay = ''
                        break
                    else:
                        time.sleep(async_wait)
                except:
                    # error means page didn't load so try again
                    time.sleep(async_wait)
            except:
                # error means page didn't load so try again
                time.sleep(async_wait)

        # get company details and seperate on size and industry
        company_size = '' # assigning as blanks as not important info and can skip if not obtained below
        company_industry = ''
        job_details = ''      
        for attempt in range(attempts):
            try:
                company_details = wd.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='mt5 mb2']/div[2]").text
                if " · " in company_details:
                    company_size = company_details.split(" · ")[0]
                    company_industry = company_details.split(" · ")[1]
                else:
                    company_size = company_details
                    company_industry = ''
                job_details = wd.find_element(By.ID, "job-details").text.replace("\n", " ")
                break
            except: 
                time.sleep(click_wait)

        # append (a) line to file
        date_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d%b%Y-%H:%M:%S")
        search_keyword = search_keyword.replace("%20", " ")
        list_job = [date_time, search_keyword, search_count, job_id, job_title, company, location, remote, update_time, applicants, job_pay, job_time, job_position, company_size, company_industry, job_details]
        list_jobs.append(list_job)

    with open(file, "a") as f:
        w = csv.writer(f)
        w.writerows(list_jobs)
        list_jobs = []
    
    logging.info(f"Page {round(search_page/25) + 1} of {round(search_count/25)} loaded for {search_keyword}")
    search_page += 25

    return search_page, search_count, url_search
```

Third_and_Final_Cell:

```
# create logging file
logging = create_logfile()

# create daily csv file
date = datetime.date.today().strftime('%d-%b-%y')
file = f"output/{date}.csv"
create_file(file, logging)

# login to linkedin and assign webdriver to variable
wd = login(logging)

# URL search terms focusing on what type of skills are required for Data Analyst & Data Scientist
search_keywords = ['Machine Learning Engineer', 'Data Scientist', 'Data Engineer']
    # Titles to remove as search is too long
    # ['Business Analyst', 'Operations Analyst', 'Marketing Analyst', 'Product Analyst',
    # 'Analytics Consultant', 'Business Intelligence Analyst', 'Quantitative Analyst',  'Data Architect',
    # 'Data Engineer', 'Machine Learning Engineer', 'Machine Learning Scientist']
search_location = "Canada"
search_remote = "true" # filter for remote positions
search_posted = "r86400" # filter for past 24 hours

# Counting Exceptions
exception_first = 0
exception_second = 0

for search_keyword in search_keywords:
    search_keyword = search_keyword.lower().replace(" ", "%20")

# Loop through each page and write results to csv
    search_page = 0 # start on page 1
    search_count = 1 # initiate search count until looks on page
    while (search_page < search_count) and (search_page != 1000):
        # Search each page and return location after each completion
        try:
            search_page, search_count, url_search = page_search(wd, search_location, search_keyword, search_remote, search_posted, search_page, search_count, file, logging)
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f'(1) FIRST exception for {search_keyword} on {search_page} of {search_count}, retrying...')
            logging.error(f'Current URL: {url_search}')
            logging.error(e)
            logging.exception('Traceback ->')
            exception_first += 1
            time.sleep(5) 
            try:
                search_page, search_count, url_search = page_search(wd, search_location, search_keyword, search_remote, search_posted, search_page, search_count, file, logging)
                logging.warning(f'Solved Exception for {search_keyword} on {search_page} of {search_count}')
            except Exception as e:
                logging.error(f'(2) SECOND exception remains for {search_keyword}. Skipping to next page...')
                logging.error(f'Current URL: {url_search}')
                logging.error(e)
                logging.exception('Traceback ->')
                search_page += 25 # skip to next page to avoid entry
                exception_second += 1
                logging.error(f'Skipping to next page for {search_keyword}, on {search_page} of {search_count}...')

# close browser
wd.quit()

logging.info(f'LinkedIn data scraping complete with {exception_first} first and {exception_second} second exceptions')
logging.info(f'Regard all further alarms...')
```

Directly under this cell, I get this message:

```
/var/folders/px/ppxppr6d63n4bxqc03x741th0000gn/T/ipykernel_2700/2309383760.py:45: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  wd = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='./chromedriver', options=chrome_options)
```

Finally, when I run the Third and final cell, I get this error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NoSuchElementException                    Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/px/ppxppr6d63n4bxqc03x741th0000gn/T/ipykernel_2700/1777996786.py in <module>
     34         try:
---> 35             search_page, search_count, url_search = page_search(wd, search_location, search_keyword, search_remote, search_posted, search_page, search_count, file, logging)
     36         except Exception as e:

/var/folders/px/ppxppr6d63n4bxqc03x741th0000gn/T/ipykernel_2700/3436527647.py in page_search(wd, search_location, search_keyword, search_remote, search_posted, search_page, search_count, file, logging)
     74     # find the number of results
---> 75     search_count = wd.find_element(By.XPATH, "//small[@class='display-flex t-12 t-black--light t-normal']").text
     76     search_count = int(search_count.split(' ')[0].replace(',', ''))  # get number before space & remove comma (ex. "1,245 results")

/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py in find_element(self, by, value)
    829 
--> 830         return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {"using": by, "value": value})["value"]
    831 

/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    439         if response:
--> 440             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    441             response["value"] = self._unwrap_value(response.get("value", None))

/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    244             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)  # type: ignore[call-arg]  # mypy is not smart enough here
--> 245         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//small[@class='display-flex t-12 t-black--light t-normal']"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=110.0.5481.177)
Stacktrace:
0   chromedriver                        0x0000000109bee138 chromedriver + 4923704
1   chromedriver                        0x0000000109b669d3 chromedriver + 4368851
2   chromedriver                        0x00000001097af787 chromedriver + 472967
3   chromedriver                        0x00000001097f3ba3 chromedriver + 752547
4   chromedriver                        0x00000001097f3df1 chromedriver + 753137
5   chromedriver                        0x000000010983a734 chromedriver + 1042228
6   chromedriver                        0x000000010981cfdd chromedriver + 921565
7   chromedriver                        0x0000000109837c0f chromedriver + 1031183
8   chromedriver                        0x000000010981cd23 chromedriver + 920867
9   chromedriver                        0x00000001097e3a4b chromedriver + 686667
10  chromedriver                        0x00000001097e5044 chromedriver + 692292
11  chromedriver                        0x0000000109bb98fe chromedriver + 4708606
12  chromedriver                        0x0000000109bbee22 chromedriver + 4730402
13  chromedriver                        0x0000000109bc76bf chromedriver + 4765375
14  chromedriver                        0x0000000109bbfe80 chromedriver + 4734592
15  chromedriver                        0x0000000109b90975 chromedriver + 4540789
16  chromedriver                        0x0000000109be1e78 chromedriver + 4873848
17  chromedriver                        0x0000000109be1ff5 chromedriver + 4874229
18  chromedriver                        0x0000000109bf66de chromedriver + 4957918
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007ff814d794e1 _pthread_start + 125
20  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007ff814d74f6b thread_start + 15


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/px/ppxppr6d63n4bxqc03x741th0000gn/T/ipykernel_2700/1777996786.py in <module>
     36         except Exception as e:
     37             logging.error(f'(1) FIRST exception for {search_keyword} on {search_page} of {search_count}, retrying...')
---> 38             logging.error(f'Current URL: {url_search}')
     39             logging.error(e)
     40             logging.exception('Traceback ->')

NameError: name 'url_search' is not defined
```

I am using Chrome Version 110.0.5481.177 (Official Build) (x86_64)

My WebDriver version:

```
$ ./chromedriver --version
ChromeDriver 110.0.5481.77 (65ed616c6e8ee3fe0ad64fe83796c020644d42af-refs/branch-heads/5481@{#839})
(base)
```

My installed version of selenium:

```
$ pip3 show selenium
Name: selenium
Version: 4.8.2
Summary: 
Home-page: https://www.selenium.dev
Author: 
Author-email: 
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages
Requires: certifi, trio, trio-websocket, urllib3
Required-by: 
(base)
```

I would sincerely appreciate any help with this. Thanks.

Comment: As I said in a comment on your last question, the relevant message here is `NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//small[@class='display-flex t-12 t-black--light t-normal']"}`. What does that tell you?

Comment: (Also, you have copied the entire last question into here with a different error message. Please tailor each question to the actual problem you are facing. Most of this code is irrelevant. Questions should contain a [mre], emphasis on "minimal". Don't just dump everything here and make us dig through it. See [ask], which says in part "**Pretend you're talking to a busy colleague** and have to sum up your entire question in one sentence: what details can you include that will help someone identify and solve your problem?".)

Comment: What do you expect us to do? As I wrote in your previous question, the code is made for an older version of selenium than you have.

Comment: @EmanuelP, the error message here is different. But you're right: it's very hard to tell how the two questions differ.

Comment: (Hint for OP: your XPath selector isn't matching anything in the source of whatever you are trying to scrape. Most, maybe _all_, of the Python code you show above is completely irrelevant. You should be looking at your selector and the source of whatever page you are trying to search to figure out why one doesn't match the other.)

Comment: @Chris, I am a python student. As I mentioned in my previous comment, I am not an expert, and therefore, I honestly don't know which code is relevant or not...which is exactly why people like me come to stackoverflow to begin with.

Comment: @JustinHenson, I'm not asking you to be an expert. I'm asking you to read the error message and [put an effort to understand it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/354577). You can [edit] this question to remove the irrelevant stuff and add missing information.